# use the variable name Python. getattr()?

Tags: variables, getattr

I have a list:
car =['VW', 'Toyota', 'Audi']

I want to use the string 'car' without defining a new variable (just humor me, please.)

Can it be done?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is very unclear on what you want to achieve and what you have tried. Please try to update your question with more details.

Comment: I want to be able to use my list name as a string  'car' without defining a new variable. Sorry I tried to keep my question as simple as possible.